# R if-else not working

Tags: r

What is wrong with this if-else in my R program?

```
if(is.na(result)[1])
    print("NA")
else
    coef(result)[[1]]
```

I'm getting an error:

```
> if(is.na(result)[1])
+   print("NA")
> else
Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
>   coef(result)[[1]]
```

So then I added curly braces around the if and the else and now I get this error:

```
> if(is.na(result)[1]) {
+     print("NA")
Error: unexpected input in:
"if(is.na(result)[1]) {
¬"
> } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>     coef(result)[[1]]
Error: unexpected input in "¬"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: @downvoter, please provide a comment if you downvote.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is that you are lacking curly braces.  Try

```
if(is.na(result)[1]) {
    print("NA")
} else {
    coef(result)[[1]]
}
```

This matters less when your source an entire file at once but for line-by-line parsing (eg when you enter at the prompt) you have to tell R that more code is coming.

Comment: Or put the other way, the `if` part of the `if`-`else` statement is a syntactically valid, complete statement, which R evaluates. When it then encounters the `else`, as far as R is concerned this is a fresh statement and you can't call/use `else` like that.

Comment: Please see updated question. I am getting more errors now.

Comment: You may need to start from a clean slate.  How do you execute that function?  Source a file?

Comment: +1: it seem to work as in the code in my answer below

Comment: It's also worth noting that the else must come after the curly bracket on the same line, you cannot start the else on a new line.

Comment: Looks like R is picky about how you write the if { } else { }: '} else {' must be on the same line.  In C I got used to write '}\nelse {' R give you an syntax error.

Comment: That is  FAQ and it has to do with parser and line by line versus whole file mode.  In short use K&R style with the opening one on the same line.

Answer (score 8):

I think your problem is signaled with this error message:

```
"if(is.na(result)[1]) {
¬"
```

Notice that strange little symbol? You have gotten a non-printing character that looks like one of those old IBM end-of-line markers. It could be problem with your LOCALE strings or with your keyboard mapping or with code you got off the Internet. Hard to tell, but you should definitely try to get rid of them by backspacing over them/

Answer (score 4):

Without curly brackets, the `if ... else ...` construct should be on one line only:

```
if(is.na(result)[1]) print("NA") else coef(result)[[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one condition and two results it's syntactically easier to use `ifelse()`

```
ifelse(is.na(result)[1], 
   print("NA"),
   coef(result)[[1]]
)
```

Comment: You have to be careful with `ifelse()`; it will return an object with the same *length* and attributes as the test clause. We can see how this might be a problem via `ifelse(FALSE, NA, 1:10)`, which returns `1`, not `1:10`. If `coef(result)[[1]]` is more complex that the test, then your suggestion will fail. It might be syntactically simpler, but it isn't necessarily the right tool here.

Answer (score 0):

This runs for me without errors

```
x      <- 1:5
result <- lm(c(1:3,7,6) ~ x)

if(is.na(result)[1]) {
  print("NA")
 } else {
  coef(result)[[1]]
 }
```

and produces

```
[1] -0.7
```

Comment: Although it might be better to do print(coef(.....)) - since that seems to be the intention here (rather than return a value) and the next question from this poster will likely be 'why doesnt this print out in my script file?'.

Comment: @Spacedman: all I was trying to do was show that there are circumstances where Dirk Eddelbuettel's code could run without an error message.

Comment: Ah, I guess my comment applies to Dirk's answer too...